# Angular, output from function on expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to know if it is possible to do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat='article in articles | filter:search'>
...
    <div>
        {{marked(article.body)}}
    </div>
...
</div>
```

So I want to execute the "marked" function, passing the article body as a parameter and display the generated output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, no problem with that syntax ! :)

All you need is to make sur the `marked` function is **defined in the right scope**.
For instance, let's assume you are in the `ArticleCtrl` controller :

```
app.controller('ArticleCtrl', function($scope) {

    // Declare the method in the controller's scope
    $scope.marked = function(article_body) {

         // do whatever you want here
         // and don't forget to return the expected result
         return "LOVE CAPS! " + article_body.toUpperCase();
    };
 });
```

You can then use `{{ marked(something) }}` in you template.

Comment: Ty very much :) Worked like a charm!

Comment: Good news. Have fun ! o/

Comment: Just a suggestion, for this type or data transformation is recommended build a filter, it use the same logic and can be reused across the whole app.

Answer (score 2):

it's possible, but make sure that function will be $scope function.

Of course call function in ng-repeat isn't good idea, try to re think about your architecure and maybe create some model for it.